# Is it possible that `netif_rx(skb)` will cause an out-of-order, when PCI-interrupts are using the two cores of the CPU?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm using Linux version 2.6.32.28, and I just wonder: Because there is one queue per CPU when using `netif_rx(skb)`, and in case that the PCI-interrupt will be handled using the two of the CPU's cores (now it uses just one, another good question is why), how is that the kernel doesn't mess up the order of the received packages? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Linux version 2.6.32.28 there is basically NAPI is used in this case if very first packet comes then the interrupt is generated & its related handler is used to process the packet.

and the packet processing is done in basically in two parts ...

**1-> hard interrupt**    in this case the packet is only placed in the kernel memory with the help of **DMA Engine** of the NIC. so to do it CPU is not required and a **sk_buff structure** is allocated for this packet. & this **sk_buff's pionter** is place in the CPU backlog.

**2-> soft iterrupt**    in this case there is a soft interrupt is generated which is responsible for removing the packet from cpu backlog & process it for upper layer in the network stack.

& for your question uses of  2 cpu core there is used only one cpu core because in **NAPI**
if another packet comes during the processing of the previous one then there is no interrupt generated but only this packet is placed in the linux-kernel with the help of DMA. & the running interrupt just pics the packet & continue its processing.